# Python 3 - Two identical strings are not matching through ==

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, equals

I have a `string` pulled from an excel spreadsheet, call it `x`. When using the `print` statement it prints the word `PLANT`

```
print(x)
PLANT
```

When I do the following:

```
if x == 'PLANT':
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

It always prints NO.

I believe this is caused by the `==` checking something more fundamental than just the surface string. I tried to investigate further by using the ascii command, but this does not show any difference either.

```
ascii(x)
```

Are there any other commands I could try to distinguish `x` from `PLANT` and understand why they are not matching?

---

Things tested

```
repr(x)
'PLANT'

type(x)
<class 'str'>

ascii(x)
'PLANT'
```

Difference found:

```
id(x)
30805824

id('PLANT')
28515008
```

Comment: Have you looked at `repr(x)`? How was it *"pulled from an excel spreadsheet"*; are you sure it's a string rather than some special cell representation?

Comment: try `if x.strip() == 'PLANT':`

Comment: Try `len(x)` and check the output is `5` or not

Comment: repr(x) returns 'PLANT' and repr('PLANT') return 'PLANT'

Comment: x.strip() had no effect

Comment: Ok, and what is the result of `type(x)`?

Comment: Can you show us more code (example from the moment x is read from spreadsheet and this comparison

Comment: you'd better upload your excel file and all your code for others to test

Comment: There is not enough information here. Based on what you're saying the equality should pass.  Instead of `else: print('NO')`, try `else: print('x')` and see if something is modifying the value along the way.

Comment: x and 'PLANT' has the same len, type, and repr but different id.

Comment: Strings aren't compared on identity, though. There is something seriously wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a chance of getting spaces around the letters. So it's better to do stripping the space characters before checking the condition.

```
if x.strip() == 'PLANT':
```

Comment: what's the output of `[ord(i) for i in x]` ?

Comment: [ord(i) for i in x] returns [80, 76, 65, 78, 84]. [ord(i) for i in 'PLANT] returns [80, 76, 65, 78, 84]

Comment: Oh, i can't able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x.strip() == 'PLANT':
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue, '\u00a0' can considered as space, if you read strings from a file, the chances are characters seem identical but completely different behind the scene.

solving this issue is not that much of a pain, however if you have this problem in your database, it might be difficult to look it up.

```
str1 = "Concrete Shear Walls"
str2 = "Concrete\u00a0Shear\u00a0Walls" # these two are identical on the surface
# Replace all non-breaking space characters with regular space characters
str2 = str2.replace('\u00a0', ' ')

if str1 == str2:
    print("The strings are equal.")
else:
    print("The strings are not equal.")
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and found that the value I had read from a file was NUL terminated ('\0') whereas the python string i was comparing against was not.

Rather than just calling strip which will remove spaces, call strip with the specific character you are attempting to remove.

```
if x.strip('\0') == "PLANT":
     print("match")
```

I found my issue using

```
print([ord(i) for i in x])
```

as suggested by Avinash Raj.

I realize this didn't seem to work for the original poster but since this solved a very similar problem I was facing I wanted to post here in case it helps others.